# AWS Redshift Data API execute-statement using parameters with UNLOAD

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm using AWS Redshift Data API to execute an SQL query on a data warehouse table.
My usecase involves filtering based on client inputs, which I want to supply as [Parameters](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/redshiftdata/model/ExecuteStatementRequest.html#parameters()) to prevent any chances of SQL injection attacks.

I'm also using an [UNLOAD] statement to dump the results from this query onto an S3 location.

However, I'm unable to find a way to use both in a single statement.

Sample case tried :

```
aws redshift-data execute-statement --cluster-identifier mycluster --database mydb --db-user myuser --sql "UNLOAD ('SELECT * from table_name1 where attribute1 = :attr1 ') TO 's3://result-bucket/1234' iam_role '<Role ARN>' --parameters "name=attr1,value=attribute_test"
```

I also tried wrapping `:attr1` under 2 single-quotations as `'':attr1''`, but that is failing as well.

Comment: Can you try using `batch-execute-statement` and provide two statements? The first would be the select with parameters which would create a temporary table, and the second would unload the temporary table to S3.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation from AWS](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/rds-data/execute-statement.html) (have a look at the examples section), your parameters should be provided as string-formatted JSON.

Try the following:

```
aws redshift-data execute-statement --cluster-identifier mycluster --database mydb --db-user myuser --sql "UNLOAD ('SELECT * from table_name1 where attribute1 = :attr1 ') TO 's3://result-bucket/1234' iam_role '<Role ARN>' --parameters "[{\"name\": \"attr1\", \"value\": {\"stringValue\": "attribute_test"}}]
```